# asp web application could not load some data from database when deployed in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis

my asp web application could not load some data from a database when deployed in iis.
i do realized my appliction in windows 7 32 bit it works correctly in my iis 32 bit, but the when i deploy it in other server Windows server 2008 R2 64 bit with a iis 32 bit for the first versions worked fine but the latest does not.

any help please.

Comment: what does "could not load some data from database" mean?  Did you get an error?

Comment: In your DB connection string, are you using "integrated security=True"?  Are you using OleDb or SqlClient?

Comment: i work fine in some views it does retrieve the data from the database with no problem, but i could not load the data from database to views in others ones

Comment: Do you get an exception, or just no data back? If you just get no data back, are you sure the data is actually in the database? How are you accessing the database? Direct SQL queries, an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate, stored procedures, etc? This question has far too little information to be answerable at the moment...

Comment: i want to notice the same application is deployed in windows 7 it work fine but in windows server not, in addition i have an earlier version i does work perfectly also in windows server, but that i'm working on know not, i do not know where is the problem. no exception juste an empty views.